# Traefik rewrite to https while preserving URL

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I want to rewrite all my http requests to https.
The problem is

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
```

does no preserve the entire URL and regex/replace does not work because I need to use

```
PathPrefixStrip
```

Are there any other possible ways to achieve my goal?